# How to create an interactive map in R which you can hover over and see statistics?

Tags: r, geography

I'm trying to create an interactive map in R based on country data I have. So for instance, suppose we have a data frame like this:

```
        population labor_market
USA     350        125
UK      67         23
```

I want to take a country row, e.g. USA, and run some code which will output a simple map of the USA. Then, when you scroll over the map with a cursor, it'll have a dividing line down the centre. When the cursor is on the left hand side, it'll say 'population: 350'. When the cursor is on the right hand side, it'll say 'labour market: 125'.

Does anyone know how to do something similar to this? I'm asking in R since I'm familiar with the environment, but open to the idea of another language/software if easier.

Comment: should be possible using `leaflet` for presentation,  in combination with some functions from the `sf`-package for data preparation.. but you should rellay write some code yourself first and then ask questions about passages you get stuck on. I seriously doubt anyone here is wiling to write the entire code for you.

Comment: Here is a [good introduction to `leaflet` in R](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/). You can either include your leaflet map in an rmarkdown document or a shiny web app.